# GET and POST on the same page?

Tags: php, post, redirect, get

EDIT: Answer found! Thank you very much people, a lot of answers worked, I chose the hidden field answer as it was easiest :D

I am creating a commenting script and I came across a problem. I am having to use $_POST and $_GET on the same page, which I don't think makes sense.

I am very new to php and am training myself.

I have a page named viewVerses.php - this has a lists of verses. When someone follows the reply link,

```
echo '<br /><a href="reply.php?verseid='.$verseid.'">Reply</a>';
```

I'm passing the verseid (commenting on bible verses) into the reply.php, so that a query may be made with that verseid. (This is so that the user can still see the verse he/she is commenting on).

Now reply.php has the form in it for posting a reply. The form goes to postReply.php

This is in postReply.php

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$body = $_POST['body'];
$verseid = $_GET[verseid];
```

Can I get the verseid from the url and the POST the values from the form in the same page?

If not, is there a way I can do this better? Remember, I am new at php and probably won't implement a solution that is super hard. I have to get it for my to put it in my site.

I hope this is clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would add a hidden input to the comment form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="verseid" value="
<?php echo $_GET['verseid']; ?>
" />
```

That way, in postReply.php, you can access it using `$_POST['verseid']`.

Comment: This one is probably the easiest solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can. The method of a form (in a html page) can be POST and the action URL can contain "GET" arguments being something like `process.php?vid=1001` so to say. So in `process.php` you'll have `vid` as $_GET and the rest of data from the form as $_POST.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, just set the action of the form to postReply.php?verseid=id_of_the_verse this way when an user submits a reply, in the POST array will be the reply related data and in the GET the id of the verse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to mix both GET and POST values with one request. The problem you have is probably that you pass the GET value to `reply.php`, which then passes POST values to `postReply.php`. So, unless you tell `reply.php` to send that GET value as well, it will get lost.

You can do this by either specifying the GET value in the `action` parameter of the `form` tag, or you could even switch to a POST value with that, by adding a `<input type="hidden" name="verseid" value="<?php echo $verseid; ?>" />` to the form.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may seem counter-intuitive an HTTP request can come in with both `Form` and `QueryString` data. Like robertbasic says you can access them both via there respective arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Using a form with a hidden input (`<input type="hidden" name="verseid" value="..." />`) is probably the cleanest way of doing things.

PHP also defines the [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) global array in addition to `$_GET` and `$_POST`. In general you should use *either* `$_GET` or `$_POST` but in this case where `verseid` is being passed for both methods, it might be more convenient to use `$_REQUEST['verseid']`. This way you need not care about the HTTP method being used on your script.