# Can a $_GET and a $_POST be used on the same page one under the other

Tags: php, post, get

I am using these two lines of code:

```
$event  = $_GET['event'];
$email1 = $_POST['e_email'];
```

in my script, but I am always getting an error that says:

```
Undefined index: event in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql\trial_rsvp.php on line 15
```

where is the problem?

If needed please ask for the complete code!

Answer (score 1):

That error is a notice generated for accessing a index not defined in your array.

For example, if `$_GET['event']` was not set, when you try to access its value, it will generate a notice.

You ignore notices by changing the `error_reporting` configuration in `php.ini` or even better, use functions like `empty` or `isset` to make sure the index is defined.

Comment: I may ignore the error but then i am unable to use the variable that i am trying to use using $_Get

Answer (score 0):

if your URI doesn't have `?event=something` or similar in it, you will get that notice, because the $_GET array won't have that index defined in it. fix:

```
if (!empty($_GET['event'])) {
    $event =$_GET['event'];
}
```

Comment: I checked for that, i think there is something wrong with using both the functions simultaneously

Comment: would you try to `print_r($_GET);` and post it here, please?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033584/get-and-post-on-the-same-page solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$event = isset ( $_GET ['event'] ) ? $_GET ['event'] : null;
$email = isset ( $_POST ['e_email'] ) ? $_POST ['e_email'] : null;
```

This would help you set the default values